# Leveraging ui-router in Angular with tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

I have an Angular SPA that is using `ui.router`. One page has 4 tabs on it. Currently, one controllers supports all 4 tabs - this is unsustainable as the code is becoming messy (too much logic per tab).

I see two solutions:
1. These shouldn't be tabs; they should be separate pages (not ideal, though).
2. There is some way to associate portions of a controller with only certain tabs (or maybe a different controller with each tab?) or some way to break a single controller up into smaller components.

Any ideas on the latter (#2) would be terrific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple routes that point to the same template/controller
Then in that 'tab group' controller have an `ng-controller` inside each tab.
The tab will be activated depending on the `$location.path()` value

I created a simple plunk here http://plnkr.co/edit/88SPMteu9MFFbqMc0cYy